Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как" в данном случае?
Отзываются о нём, как о грамотном специалисте.

Есть одно правило:

Обороты с "как", тесно связанные со сказуемым, не обособляются.

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как" в данном случае?
Нет.
Без "как" теряется смысл (суть не в том, что о нём отзываются, а в том, что о нём отзываются, словно он грамотный специалист).
Исправленный вариант
Отзываются о нём как о грамотном специалисте.


Самое забавное в этой теме то, что предложение имеет два решения,  это только кажется, что оно одно.
Почему? А это трехчастный оборот, и там по грамматике всегда два решения: сравнение (два ударения) или обстоятельственный оборот (одно ударение только на обороте). Решение зависит от структуры предложения и контекста.
Углубляться в подробности не буду, но приведу контекст для двух вариантов.
(1) Почему вы сомневаетесь по поводу его кандидатуры? ОтзывАются о нем, как о грАмотном специалисте.
(2)  Отзываются о нем как о грАмотном специалисте, но это надо дополнительно провЕрить.
